# Is there a way to force xargs to send multiple lines at once?

Tags: bash, concurrency, batch-processing, xargs

I have a job that reads data from a \n delimited stream and sends the information to xargs to process 1 line at a time.  The problem is, this is not performant enough, but I know that if I altered the program such that the command executed by xargs was sent multiple lines instead of just one line at a time, it could drastically improve the performance of my script.

Is there a way to do this?  I haven't been having any luck with various combinations of `-L` or `-n`.  Unfortunately, I think I'm also stuck with `-I` to parameterize the input since my command doesn't seem to want to take stdin if I don't use `-I`.

The basic idea is that I'm trying to simulate mini-batch processing using xargs.

Conceptually, here's something similar to what I currently have written

`contiguous-stream | xargs -d '\n' -n 10 -L 10 -I {} bash -c 'process_line {}'`

^ in the above, `process_line` is easy to change so that it could process many lines at once, and this function right now is the bottleneck.  For emphasis, above, `-n 10` and `-L 10` don't seem to do anything, my lines are still processing one at a time.

Comment: `xargs -I {} bash -c 'something with {}'` is dangerous. What if one of the lines in your stream contains `$(rm -rf ~)`?

Comment: Why do you call `bash` to execute `process_line`? If it is a standalone executable you can call it directly to avoid the security problem and some overhead. If it is a shell function or alias you can create a wrapper shell executable to call instead of `bash -c ...`.

Comment: @pabouk, ...agreed that calling an executable directly is preferred, but if the code being invoked is native shell, I'm not sure a wrapper buys anything over `bash -c`, *particularly* if you have an exported function you're trying to invoke. Could you expand?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you are right. It is just an alternative how to avoid the mentioned security issue caused by evaluation of the parameters by shell.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Multiple Lines Per Shell Invocation

Don't use `-I` here. It prevents more than one argument from being passed at a time, and is outright major-security-bug dangerous when being used to substitute values into a string passed as code.

```
contiguous-stream | xargs -d $'\n' -n 10 \
  bash -c 'for line in "$@"; do process_line "$line"; done' _
```

Here, we're passing arguments added by `xargs` out-of-band from the code, in position populated from `$1` and later, and then using `"$@"` to iterate over them.

Note that this reduces overhead inasmuch as it passes multiple arguments to each shell (so you pay shell startup costs fewer times), but it *doesn't* actually process all those arguments concurrently. For that, you want...

#### Multiple Lines In Parallel

Assuming GNU `xargs`, you can use `-P` to specify a level of parallel processing:

```
contiguous-stream | xargs -d $'\n' -n 10 -P 8 \
  bash -c 'for line in "$@"; do process_line "$line"; done' _
```

Here, we're passing 10 arguments to each shell, *and running 8 shells at a time*. Tune your arguments to taste: Higher values of `-n` spend less time starting up new shells but increase the amount of waste at the end (if one process still has 8 to go and every other process is done, you're operating suboptimally).

Comment: `-I` doesn't actually prevent more than 1 argument from being passed at a time, but no argument about the security hole.

Comment: @JoeyColeman, ...I certainly don't see any clear specification in [the POSIX  `xargs` spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/xargs.html) for how it should behave when `-I` has the implied `-L 1` overridden. Thus, it looks like any ability to work without that is an extension. Granted, I'm taking advantage of `-d`, another extension, but I'd argue a much less ambiguously-specified one. :)

Comment: @JoeyColeman, it does seem like -I prevents "batching" of parameters.  I deleted my answer because Charles' is better, but try for i in {1..100}; do echo $i; done | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -n10 and then try with -I {} echo {} and you'll see that -I definitely affects the xargs param handling.

Comment: The other trick that makes this clearer for me is to replace \n in the input stream with \0 using tr '\n' '\0' and then use xargs -0.

Comment: In GNU `xargs` it seems that if you specify `-L x` or `-n x` after `-I {}` then the effect of `-I` is completely cancelled.

Comment: Deleted my answer — `-L` after `-I` disables the `-I` entirely (my use of `echo` in tests masked this)